# Bounds for quotient of two amicable numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b$ be amicable with $a$ being the smaller of the two numbers. Are there any bounds for $\frac{a}{b}$  ?

I looked online and found that there were maximal and minimal bounds but these do not appear to be anything but just running a program up to some number and finding the lowest and highest. I was curious if there are actual bounds.

So I am really interested in numerical bounds like $ 0.333 < \frac{a}{b} <.9997$ (this is just a made up example)

If there are not any bounds better than $0 < \frac{a}{b} <1$ than I would wonder whether there are any bounds if we know that the $gcd (a,b) =5$ ?

Comment: I doubt there are any better bounds than the trivial $0<\tfrac ab<1$, but I would love to be shown wrong.

Comment: $4000783984/4001351168 \approx .999858$.

Comment: @Servaes you mean known bounds, right? There may very well (as far as I know) be only finitely many amicable pairs.

Comment: @mathworker21 thank you for your answer I am wondering if Servaes is right or if there is any better estimate

Comment: I think Servaes was wrong. He deleted his comment

Comment: @argamon I think best known lower bound is .69789 but I may be wrong

Comment: Precisely why I ask. I wonder if there is a way to guarantee that it is near there or if it can be way smaller ? I am kinda stuck

Comment: @argamon the fact that .999858 occurs suggests that an upper bound less than 1 would be very hard to prove lol. I'm thinking about lower bound now

Comment: @mathworker21 No I totally agree it seems that from the numbers it is more likely that the upper bound is close to 1 but imagining that the lower bound could be close to zero seems unrealistic

Comment: @argamon I don't see any reason why the quotient can't be arbitrarily close to 0. If you have a sketch or intuition, I'd be happy to see it. Like I don't see why there should be any information about the quotient about amicable numbers. The sum of the divisors of a number can be much larger than the number.

Comment: Just based on the known bounds I am guessing that since the minimal known bound is  about 0.69789 that finding an amicable pair that is say 0.29 for the ratio would prove challenging.

Comment: challenging is not equal to impossible though.

Comment: @argamon With Euler's theorem for amicable numbers, I constructed the following pair of amicable numbers $$2724918040393706557785752240819405848576$$ $$2724918040396184856306258038787235905536$$ with ratio $1-9\cdot 10^{-13}$